# Recycler view horizontal inside a tablayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

im a android developer and need to do this: 
[Recycler view horizontal like facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxkFa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLJww.png)
Thats one recyclerview horizontal with a tablayout, i wanna do is while the user be scrolling de recycler view his cannot swipe the tab layout.
Like facebook tab videos

Answer (score 1):

Create a recyclerView in the xml and add this code in the activity. You will achieve the horizontal scrolling without swiping the tab layout.

```
adapter = new Adapter(// pass your arguments);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
recycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: my code: 
    mRecyclerViewFilters = view.findViewById(R.id.filtrosLances);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerViewFilters.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        filters = new ArrayList<>();
        getFilters();
        mAdapter = new RecyclerFilterAdapter(getContext(), filters);
        mRecyclerViewFilters.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerViewFilters.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: Can you see your items in the recycler view?

Comment: yesss
I want to roll only the list and even if it reaches the end, I did not let go to another tab